# Max value conditional formatting rule not working in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I want the max value in Column B to show up. I put in this formula but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Here is the table

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**custom formula:** 

```
=B15=MAX(B$15:B20)
```

[image: 5]